# Eclipse shortcut to switch between editor groups

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I can use Ctrl-F6 or Ctrl-Shift-PgUp/Down to switch between files in the editor.
This works well if there is only one editor visible.

But when i have arranged the editor in two halfs, some files are left, some files are right. This is called "split window", like this example https://codeyarns.com/2010/01/04/how-to-split-window-in-eclipse/

I do not mean the split editor, where the same file is shown in two halfs.

How can I toggle between the left/right side (or however they are arranged), always to the already visible file?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the benefits of the [Emacs+ Eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/emacs).  When this is installed, the "other-window" function will be available, which does exactly what you're looking for.

Note that using the Emacs+ plugin does not require you to know anything about Emacs or Elisp.  It simply provides a large catalog of functions that are similar in spirit to what Emacs provides.

You could use the "Emacs+" keyboard scheme, which is consistent with typical Emacs bindings, but I don't use it, as I prefer to integrate Emacs+ with Eclipse, not the other way around.  I like to choose a "prefix sequence" that I use to group many functions that I like to use.  For instance, I use "Ctrl+;" (ctrl-semicolon) as that prefix.  I bound "other-window to "ctrl+; o".  You can use whatever scheme you like.  Despite my goal to use my own bindings, there are some functions that are awkward if you don't use the binding from the Emacs+ scheme, like binding "ctrl+s" to the incremental regexp search function.